# How to extract number from a list of string to be in a new column with python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this file name as follows:

```
8550 - Field Data Progress_070720.xlsx
```

and I need to get the **8550** only to be in a new column.

How can I do this with python?

Thankyou

Comment: what do you mean by new column?

Comment: Please provide more examples..

Comment: I mean, I need to extract the 8550 to appear in a new column

Answer (score 0):

As I can get the string from my filename, so I need to:

```
filename = os.path.basename(xls)
```

then from the `filename`, I want to extract `8550` only to appear in a new column.

I was thinking to use `split.str`, but I did not get the exact script to extract `only`

Thanks